# Debugging an SQLite query from a C program

Tags: c, sqlite

I have an SQL table where one of the columns has several comma separated values. The code below is supposed to go through all of them and return true if a particular value is present in the list, however it seems to only work with values other than the first value in the entry. Any ideas about where I screwed up? The query works fine when running it directly on the database file using sqlite3, so I'm sure the problem is with this function.

```
bool group_exists(char *group)
{
    int retv;
    char *param_1, *param_2;
    bool exists = false;
    sqlite3_stmt *p_stmn;

    param_1 = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    param_2 = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

    sprintf(param_1, "%s,%%", group);
    sprintf(param_2, "%%,%s,%%", group);

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT groups FROM users WHERE groups LIKE ? OR groups LIKE ?", -1, &p_stmn, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(p_stmn, 1, param_1, -1, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(p_stmn, 1, param_2, -1, NULL);
    retv = sqlite3_step(p_stmn);

    if (retv == SQLITE_ROW) {
        exists = true;
    } else if (retv != SQLITE_DONE) {
        retval_crash();
    }

    free(param_1);
    free(param_2);
    sqlite3_finalize(p_stmn);

    return exists;
}
```

Comment: Are the commas necessary? Show the expected/working query you used in sqlite3 without `?`s so I can understand the like statement you are trying to achieve. Also use `snprintf` if available, and check `sqlite3_prepare_v2 ` for [SQLITE_OK](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)

Comment: The query is "SELECT groups FROM users WHERE groups LIKE '%,foobar,%' OR groups LIKE 'foobar,%'" where foobar is the group I'm checking for. The problem is the field contains a comma separated list of values and 'foobar' shouldn't match 'foo,foobarba,' for example. I know that getting the whole string from SQLite and then matching it in C would be probably neater, but that would complicate other parts of the code, so I'm hoping to fix this instead.

Comment: *The problem is the field contains a comma separated list of values* stop right there and put a period after *values*. You might want to review your schema once you get over your immediate `sqlite3_bind_text` index problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you bind the indexes to the correct sql parameter.

```
sqlite3_bind_text(p_stmn, 1, param_1, -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(p_stmn, 2, param_2, -1, NULL);
```

Also when trying to debug sqlite be sure to check the [result codes](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#SQLITE_ABORT) to make sure everything is successful.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't notice that after staring at this code for so long.

Comment: As you can tell by my question in the comments above, I missed it to. It wasn't until I went through the documentation for each method and saw "The second argument is the index of the SQL parameter to be set. The leftmost SQL parameter has an index of 1."